# Redirect visitors from certain countries to a safe page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net website.

The website is purely for customers in the UK, although some of our suppliers may originate in the USA/Canada.

We get a lot of visitors from Africa, China, Russia etc, who quite frankly, we know are up to no good.

I thought of the possibility of detecting the originating country and redirecting to a 'safe page' for blacklisted countries.

I wondered whether this is actually achievable (do to data being available) and if so what mechanism (from a code perspective) would I use in Asp.Net.

Comment: Anybody who really wants to should be able to get around this restriction relatively trivially.  What would this achieve?  What if somebody in Russia wants to order something for a UK subsidiary?

Comment: You're going to struggle to do this without subscribing to an external service but detecting browser culture may be a good start...

Comment: @Paddy or someone connects to a UK based VPN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IPInfoDB` API to achieve this. For more information and full tutorial visit

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Find-Visitors-Geographic-Location-using-IP-Address-in-ASPNet.aspx